# Numpy: copyto returns None

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, mask

When I use `np.copyto`, it always returns `None`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((3,3))
b = np.zeros_like(a)
b[:,0] = 100
b_nonzero_mask = b.astype(bool)
c = np.copyto(a, b, where=b_nonzero_mask)
print(c)  # None
```

How is the function supposed to be used?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Python, by default, if a function does not have a return statement it returns `None`. The `np.copyto` definition does not return anything. Instead, it rewrites `a` in place.

So, you have to copy `a` beforehand:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((3,3))
b = np.zeros_like(a)
b[:,0] = 100
b_nonzero_mask = b.astype(bool)
c = np.copy(a)
np.copyto(c, b, where=b_nonzero_mask)
```

Comment: And so what if he did?

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, but the code you've provided in your answer doesn't even work.

Comment: @user3483203 I made a typo (wrote 3 instead of 0). It works now.